# CodeIgniter, header controller is not loading index method

Tags: php, debugging, codeigniter-2

Firstly I am getting no errors, I am trying to create an is_logged_in() method in my header model in Code Igniter, but nothing in the index method of the controller will load. I added die(); into it and even that wont execute, Here is my code:

header.php - controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Header extends CI_Controller {
    public function index() {
        print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
        $data = array();
        $data['title'] = 'Wenso - Timesheet';
        $username = $this->session->userdata('username');
        $this->load->view('template/header', $data);
        $this->load->model('header_model');
        $is_logged_in = $this->header_model->is_logged_in($username);
        die($is_logged_in);
    }
}
```

header_model.php - Model

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Header_model extends CI_Model {
    public function is_logged_in($username){
        $q = $this
            ->db
            ->where('email_address', $username)
            ->limit(1)
            ->get('users');

        die($q->last_query());

        if($q->row('username') != $username){
            return FALSE;
        } else {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: none of the die() functions in my code work.. Anything I add into the index function of the controller (which to my understanding is loaded by default) does not get executed...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you call that controller ? I mean, is your URL looks like http://example.com/index.php/Header ?

Comment: Do you have constructors with parent::__construct() ? You may not have $this->db inside your model if you don't have constructor and in that case you have a php error of non existing variable...

Comment: ahhhh I am not calling the controller in the url! So how can I make the call happen? The user is never going to be calling /header in the url... I need this function to be called on all pages with admin access how can I implmenet this?

Answer (score 0):

> public function __construct() { parent::__construct(); }

Add this method at your model else you wont have $this->db loaded

Answer (score 0):

As AdrienXL pointed out the controller is only loaded whern the url /controller_name is called.. This wasn;t the case in my user case scenario.

Also something worth pointing out as Sevtilo mentioned above if you create a construct method in CodeIgniter you ovewrite the dafult calls for things such as $this->db class, using:

```
public function __construct() {

    parent::__contsruct();

}
```

Will get the parent classes contsructor.

Regards
Ric

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call this code transparently (ie without having to put any extra mess in the uri) then move the code into the constructor of an extension called MY_Controller.php in application/core that looks a bit like this...

```
 class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller { 
    public function __construct() { 
       parent::__construct();
       print_r($this->session->all_userdata()); 
       $data = array(); $data['title'] = 'Wenso - Timesheet'; 
       $username = $this->session->userdata('username'); 
       $this->load->view('template/header', $data); 
       $this->load->model('header_model'); 
       $is_logged_in = $this->header_model->is_logged_in($username); 
       die($is_logged_in); 
       } 
  }
```

And then in your application/controllers files extend this class like

```
class Some_controller extends MY_Controller{
      function __construct (){
             parent::__construct();
      }

      public function index(){
           //your header code will be run before this or any other method in this class
      }

}
```

And the code from MY_Controller.php will run before any of your methods.